# Word range copy and paste not working on PS4

Tags: powershell, ms-word, powershell-4.0

In the below code the `$range2.Paste($copy)` line is not working on PS4 and below versions.

> Error: Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException
>   Exception Message: Exception calling "Paste" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Minimal Code:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$word2 = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word2.visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.open($source)
$doc2 = $word2.documents.add($template)
$range = $doc.Range()
$copy=""
$copy = $range.Copy()
$range2 = $doc2.Range()
$range2.Paste($copy)
$doc2.saveas([ref]$destination,[ref]$saveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
```

Comment: check if $range2 is $null

Comment: Good and how i can copy specific page data and paste to another word document. Here I am doing range.copy but if i need to copy page2 data in page3 of other document.

Comment: @Moerwald - Checking Range for Null is not a solution, we can just manage the exception. I am getting this issue in PS4 and below versions only.

Comment: Answer: I have got the solution for specific page range copy.            
$start = $doc2.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,[type]::Missing,'2').Start
  $end = $doc2.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,[type]::Missing,$pagecount).Start                                       
$range2 = $doc2.Range($start,$end )